# load url image using kingfisher freeze when scrolling fast

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, uiimageview, tableview, kingfisher

I have a horizontal collection view inside tableview

In each collection view there are no of images loading from url with kingfisher library

but when i scroll fast ,tableview freeze for some seconds & scrolling continue after display cells images loading completed

I'm using UICollectionViewCell xib for cell reuse

```
self.imgPhoto.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: varImageURL))
```

Comment: **It's happening due to server image loading, use this.** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746517/10150796

Comment: I try your code but after some scrolling xcode gives following error - Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Comment: Try to load image code in DispatchQueue.main.async { Here is your image load code } and check it

Comment: still freeze & slow down api call

Comment: Please Display your Collectionview cellForRowAtIndexPath Code for More Information.

Comment: let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageSmallCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ImageSmallCollectionViewCell

DispatchQueue.main.async {
NKPlaceholderImage(image: UIImage(named: “ic_default.png”), imageView: cell.imgPhoto, imgUrl: varUrl) { (image) in }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177850/discussion-between-nikunj-kumbhani-and-dharini).